MapBox Custom Nodes
I'm new to Mapbox and I'm exploring its features for a project. I want to create custom routing on the map, particularly in areas where Mapbox does not currently have roads or paths. I would like to:

Add my own custom nodes to the map.
Perform calculations like pathfinding (shortest path, etc.) using these custom nodes.

I tried looking through the documentation, but I couldn't find any articles that directly address this use case. The closest I found was the Dataset feature, but I'm not sure if that’s the correct tool for what I want to achieve.
Does Mapbox support this functionality? If so, what would be the recommended approach or tools to use within Mapbox for adding custom nodes and enabling pathfinding on them? I’m primarily working on this for mobile platforms, so if there are differences in the tools or approach compared to web apps, please let me know.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
